# Pandas condition over two/multiple column

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my sample df. I want to find if a combination exist in the df.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

output = """
name    weight   performance_l    performance_r
Arash   62.2       85           100       
Bash    91.2       90           79       
Kim     88.2       85           85      
Dim     92.1       90           95
Ghst    63.2       60           65      
"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(output), delim_whitespace=True)


if (('Arash' in df.name.values) & (90 in df.performance_l.values)):
    print('True')
```

I would like track if some combination of name and performance_l do exist or not.
here Arash doesn't have 90 in performance_l but still this gives true:

```
if (('Arash' in df.name.values) & (90 in df.performance_l.values)):
    print('True')
```

Comment: `(output.name.eq('Arash') & output.performance_l.eq(90)).any()`

Comment: More to the way you were trying to go about it `('Arash', 90) in zip(output.name, output.performance_l)`

Comment: Letting Pandas build an index `('Arash', 90) in output.set_index(['name', 'performance_l']).index`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are testing the whole column values with: df.column.values

The values for `df.name.values` are:

```
array(['Arash', 'Bash', 'Kim', 'Dim', 'Ghst'], dtype=object)
```

and for `df.performance_l.values` are:

```
array([85, 90, 85, 90, 60])
```

Your test `if (('Arash' in df.name.values) & (90 in df.performance_l.values)):` is testing if it will find `Arash` in the `name` column and `90` in the `performance_l` column, and it is true.

If your dataframe is small, I would use:

```
if ('Arash', 90) in zip(df.name.values, df.performance_l.values):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query and check if the resulting dataframe has values.

```
not df.query('name == "Arash" and performance_l == 90').empty

False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if len(df[(df['name'] == 'Arash') & (df['performance_l'] == 90)]):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

This should check both conditions being met in one row rather than checking those values exist in any one element in either columns.

Explanation:

The following code is what we usually use to filter row that have both conditions met:

```
df[(df['name'] == 'Arash') & (df['performance_l'] == 90)])]
```

And then by checking whether there are any row (by the `len()` function, we can see that if the len() return 0 then no match, non-zero then there is/are matches.